# Override serial sequence in PostgreSql with Entity Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

How do I override the serial/sequence in an ID field when adding records with Entity Framework on a PostgreSQL database?

The serial/sequence auto incrementing ID works fine, when adding records, but I need to write a migration script where the old records I migrate must maintain their old ID's.

It works fine if I just shoot an INSERT query directly to the server, but when doing with with Entity Framework, they just start from 1, 2, 3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should to reset sequence in the database before any insertions using autogenerated values. It is highly depending on table DDL. There are two example for most used ID's autogen:

```
/*
-- Be careful with these 3 lines if you already have such objects in the your DB 
drop table if exists t1;
drop table if exists t2;
drop sequence if exists seq_t2_id;
*/

-- Using serial type for ID
create table t1 (t1_id serial, t1_name char varying);
insert into t1 (t1_id, t1_name) values (22, 'aaa');
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('t1', 't1_id'), (select max(t1_id) from t1)); -- Reset serial value
insert into t1 (t1_name) values ('bbb');
select * from t1;

-- Using sequence to generate IDs
create sequence seq_t2_id;
create table t2(t2_id bigint default nextval('seq_t2_id'), t2_name char varying);
insert into t2(t2_id, t2_name) values (22, 'aaa');
select setval('seq_t2_id', (select max(t2_id) from t2)); -- Update sequence
insert into t2 (t2_name) values ('bbb');
select * from t2;
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I do a truncate of the table before I start inserting the records, and they start from 1... But I don't want them to - I want to choose the ID myself for the insert in this case.